# Chart.js 2 How will I put the dataset inside the bar if it is near the TOP?

Tags: javascript, ajax, chart.js, chart.js2

[image: Data Overflow]

So I'm working on with this graph using Chart.js v2.1.4. The top data that overflows must adjust itself and reposition inside the vertical bar. So when a specific dataset is near the maximum, the dataset should be inside the vertical bar. Someone please help.

```
 animation: {
       duration: 500,
       easing: "easeOutQuart",
       onComplete: function () {
       var ctx = this.chart.ctx;
     ctx.font =Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily, 'normal', Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

     this.data.datasets.filter(dataset => 
     !dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].hidden).forEach(function 
     (dataset) {
     for (var i = 0; i < dataset.data.length; i++) {
     var model = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta)[0]].data[i]._model, scale_max = dataset._meta[Object.keys(dataset._meta[0]].data[i]._yScale.maxHeight;
      ctx.fillStyle = '#000';
      var y_pos = model.y - 5;
     // Make sure data value does not get overflown and hidden
     // when the bar's value is too close to max value of scale
     // Note: The y value is reverse, it counts from top down
     if ((scale_max - model.y) / scale_max >= 0.80)
        y_pos = model.y + 20; 
        console.log(y_pos);
        verticalLabel(ctx, model, addCommas(dataset.data[i]), 50, 20, 4, y_pos);

         }
      });               
    }
  }
```

This is the verticalLabel function:

```
function verticalLabel(ctx, data, dataToSplit, topOffset, spaceBetween, commaGap, why_pos) {
        var i = 0, prev = 0;
        console.log(data.y - spaceBetween * i - topOffset / why_pos);
        for (x of dataToSplit.toString().split("").reverse()) {
        if (x.indexOf(",") > -1) {
        ctx.fillText(x, data.x + commaGap, prev - topOffset / why_pos);
        } else {
        ctx.fillText(x, data.x, data.y - spaceBetween * i - topOffset / why_pos);
        i++;
        }
    var prev = data.y - spaceBetween * i;
    }   
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found the answer, I edited the else{} block under verticalLabel function:

```
function verticalLabel(ctx, data, dataToSplit, topOffset, spaceBetween, commaGap, why_pos) {
    var i = 0, prev = 0;

    for (x of dataToSplit.toString().split("").reverse()) {
       if (x.indexOf(",") > -1) {
        ctx.fillText(x, data.x + commaGap, prev - topOffset / why_pos);
        } else {
        ctx.fillText(x, data.x, why_pos - spaceBetween * i - topOffset / why_pos);
        i++;
            }
        var prev = data.y - spaceBetween * i;
        }   
    }
```

my code under animation: {}

```
if ((scale_max - model.y) / scale_max >= 0.60)
    y_pos = model.y + 90; 
    verticalLabel(ctx, model, addCommas(dataset.data[i]), 50, 20, 4, y_pos);
```

[image: almost there graph]

It is somehow working but still not perfect. I LOST the COMMAS when inserted inside the bar graph. I still need help.

Comment: nevermind I got it. hahaha.
under verticalLabel I edited 

**var prev = why_pos - spaceBetween * i;